# How to change a 'php.ini' setting in a PHP file

Tags: php, php-ini

I am installing vtiger6 on a client's server. I don't have access to the *php.ini* file. I have tried to change some *php.ini* setting through my *index.php* file. Some settings work fine:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
ini_set('log_errors', 'off');
```

But I am not able to set up the following:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED');
ini_set('allow_call_time_pass_reference', '1');
```

And also I need to change the following too. I don't know whether this is right or not.

```
ini_set('max_file_uploads', 300);
ini_set('memory_limit', '240M');
ini_set('max_input_time ', 600);
```

Comment: How did you know error_reporting setting is not working? did you expect errors to show up or to disappear?

Comment: @KraneBird while installing vtiger it will show Recommended PHP Settings and present value. in its `error_reporting` present value is `NOT RECOMMENDED`

Comment: There is a ***trailing space*** for `max_input_time` (also in [the initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1d362f2b-c8d9-476a-ad64-8bc5ab898e36/view-source)). Will that make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why *error_reporting* did work not is you set its value to the following string. `'E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED'`. But it should not be a string. E_* values are PHP constants and should be used outside quotes like:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_WARNING ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```

Also you are using binary XOR (^) between these constants, which is unusual. The suggested value for a production environments is to use `E_ALL` alone, for debugging. If you want all errors except `E_DEPRECATED`, you can use `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`.

Some PHP settings cannot be changed with `ini_set`. You can check the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) for which variables allow setting on the file level. For example, `max_file_uploads` is only changeable from the *php.ini* file ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads)).

Answer (score 3):

Set *error_reporting* by using function *[error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)*. Go through the php.net manual.

For the *allow_call_time_pass_reference* entry, it can be set in *php.ini* and *httpd.conf*.

You can create a *php.ini* file in your directory on the server and store settings there.

Answer (score 1):

Not all configuration in php.ini can be change on runtime with `ini_set()`. You can only set `allow_call_time_pass_reference`, `max_file_uploads`, `memory_limit`, and `max_input_time` in your php.ini.

But, if you want to show error you have to use both `ini_set('display_errors')` and `ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL)`

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL);
```

References:

- http://sg3.php.net/ini_set
- http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php
- http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Answer (score 0):

use error_reporting instead of ini_set like 
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

use this in your .htaccess file that is existing in root folder
php_value post_max_size 30M
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M

that should work